# Outliner takes up the entire right side

Tags: outliner

[image]My outliner takes up the entire right side and I can't see the icons for properties, materials, modifiers, etc. I dragged the shader screen from the bottom to the top and dragged it back down when the properties screen seemed to be joined to the same bar when I moved the shader screen up and down. After that, the view in the outliner has taken up the entire right column and I can't get it back. If I close Blender and restart it's the same, unless I start a brand new Blender project then all the views are correct. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: This is so basic, so consider watching Blender basics at Blender channel. Here is direct link to managing interface: https://youtu.be/8XyIYRW_2xk?t=62

Comment: Agree with @Crantisz, but if you want to open a Blender file which has been saved with the layout screwed up, start Blender then go to File > Open, press 'N' in the file selector to bring up its side panel and uncheck 'Load UI' before selecting and loading the file.

Comment: Unchecking load UI worked. Thank You for the quick response...Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Split new area and join with properties:

[image]

If you don't know how to split and join areas, consider watching Blender basics at Blender channel. Here is direct link to managing interface: https://youtu.be/8XyIYRW_2xk?t=62